# Xcodebuild cannot build framework library for simulator sdk

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm having some issues when I try to build a framework using xcodebuild. My xcode version is 6.1.

This line works well:

```
xcodebuild -target Knot3DLib -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos
```

However it doesn't work:

```
xcodebuild -target Knot3DLib -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator
```

It says:

> No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=i386 x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=arm64
>   armv7 armv7s).

I've no defined neither i386 nor x86_64 as archs in my project, so why does xcodebuild try to build i386? Here's my architecture build settings:

[image: build settings]

I can run the project from Xcode in both simulator and devices.

I've tried other similar questions but none of them worked for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simulator is just that, a simulator. Xcode builds code that runs on a simulated environment on your computer. Your computer has an intel CPU and your phone has an ARM CPU. The compiler generates different code for these processors.

The error:

```
No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=i386 x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=arm64 armv7 armv7s).
```

Tells you that the architecture you are trying to compile for: `ARCHS=i386 x86_64` is not in the list of `VALID_ARCHS`.

`i386` and `x86_64` are the architectures that intel CPUs use. If you are trying to build a framework with `xcodebuild` and you want to be able to link against the simulator sdk you need to add `i386` and `x86_64` to your list of `VALID_ARCHS`

Comment: It works, thanks a lot. If one day you come to Seville(Spain) I owe you a beer :).

Comment: In my Cocoa Touch Framework, i386 and x86_64 is NOT in the build settings. Where is it coming from?!